# Haskell - Debug Print in if block

Tags: debugging, haskell

I want to debug my program by printing something

For example,

```
isPos n 
    | n<0       = False
    | otherwise = True
```

I want something like:

```
isPos n 
    | n<0       = False AND print ("negative")
    | otherwise = True  AND print ("positive")
```

Is it possible to do in Haskell?

Comment: Read before http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Debugging  Read after http://stackoverflow.com/questions/672979/what-is-a-good-way-to-debug-haskell-code?rq=1

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As hammar said, use `trace` from the `Debug.Trace` module. A tip I have found useful is to define the function `debug`:

```
debug = flip trace
```

You could then do

```
isPos n
  | n < 0     = False `debug` "negative"
  | otherwise = True  `debug` "positive"
```

The benefit of this is that it is easy to enable/disable the debug printing
during development. To remove the debug printing, simply comment out rest of
the line:

```
isPos n
  | n < 0     = False -- `debug` "negative"
  | otherwise = True  -- `debug` "positive"
```

Comment: I've often also found the variation `debug = (flip trace) False` useful. If I have a guards-based function definition, I simply insert a (or multiple) `| debug ("Interesting value is " ++ show whatever) = undefined` as the first guard(s). The trace is always run, but since `debug x` is always `False`, the guard always fails and the program behaves as normal. This makes it easy to quickly inspect values, at least in functions that already have guards.

Comment: You can also have the following two definitions at the top of your file, and simply toggle between them to toggle debug mode:

`debug = flip trace` and 
`debug a b = a`

Comment: Apparently I can't edit that comment anymore; a simpler way is to have a `doDebug` boolean and define `debug` as `debug a b = if doDebug then trace b a else a`

Answer (score 19):

Use [`Debug.Trace.trace`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Debug-Trace.html#v%3atrace).

```
import Debug.Trace

isPos n 
  | n < 0     = trace "negative" False
  | otherwise = trace "positive" True
```